# Deliver command-line tool via NuGet for use in post-build events in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I've developed a command-line utility that takes .NET assemblies as input and generates XML as output for use by another product.

Ideally I'd have it:

- Delivered via NuGet as a solution-level package
- Accessible in post-build events at the project level
- **Bit where I'm stuck:** Accessible in that post-build event just by specifying the command name without path

  - i.e. *MyTool.exe /i $(TargetPath)* as opposed to *..\packages\ToolName-1.0.0.0\tools\MyTool.exe /i $(TargetPath)*

The first two things I can already do, and a post-build event command as above works just fine but only if I first open the Package Manager Console (even if I don't type any commands, just have to open it) - seemingly it's doing something cool with paths when it fires up so that I don't have to specify the ..\packages\ToolName-1.0.0.0\tools\MyTool.exe.

Is it possible for my NuGet package to use an Init.ps1 script (or some other mechanism) to adjust paths so that I needn't specify the full relative path to the tool when writing a post-build event, or to otherwise include run tool as a post-build step automatically?

*Note* - I accept NuGet mightn't be the ideal vector for delivering this sort of tool, but it would be convenient.

Comment: Big ups to this question. I am surprised this is not a feature of nuget since it has been part of MSBuild for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the folks that come across this;

I've seen people use a nuget package for this, e.g. see nswag.msbuild:
https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag.MSBuild

In short the nuget package contains the tool as a command line utility executable. It also defines some buildprops that define the path to this tool (something along the lines of `/packages/myToolNugetPkg/mytool.exe`) Then you can use this property in an msbuild task.

Also .NET core supports 'tools', which is exactly what you needed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey (which technically qualifies as using NuGet) has a very cool magical "shimming" facility.

In brief, any executable in your package will be available on the PATH automatically. [It's very cool.](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-shim)

Answer (score -2):

This might help you ->
http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2011/06/24/how-to-use-a-tool-installed-by-nuget-in-your-build-scripts/

I used the solution with the wildcard in the 'CD' command, so my postbuild looks like this:

```
CD "$(SolutionDir)packages\ToolName*\tools"
MyTool.exe
```

Comment: That'd help if the person installing the package used that as their post-build command (so I could update the tool's documentation to reflect that), but doesn't add the tool's folder to the path which was the original aim.

Note I'm writing the package rather than consuming it, so the goal is to do something as a package writer to make it as easy as possible to consume the package in a post-build step.